# Android autosync and background

Tags: android

How do I get the status, ie whether the background and autosync is ON or OFF in android programtically?

Comment: background and autosync of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these method to check the status of your system settings:

1. [Auto-Sync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getMasterSyncAutomatically%28%29)
2. [Background Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting%28%29)